# Consulta por agrupación y condicionales? Cómo se hace esta consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito agrupar los registros que se repitan, en base al embarque y al productor y que se sumen los que se repitan, por ejemplo:

Embarque: 2
prodductor:3
kilos:537

Según la tabla 'fruta' de abajo....... PERO ME HAGO BOLAS :(, si lo hago con el `group by` pero como pongo la condición de que sea cuando se repita el embarque pero también el productor

[image: Tabla fruta]

Comment: En el `GROUP BY` puedes poner las columnas que desees, por ejemplo: `GROUP BY Embarque, IdProductor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando la función SUM() puedes hacer esto

```
SELECT embarque, productor, SUM(kilos) FROM tabla GROUP BY embarque, productor;
```

Comment: Gracias Paulo44, mi error era que ponía and en lugar de un , en el group by